# How do I make an interactive tkinter text box, then entry box, then text box as a response to the entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I cannot get it to first show the question a text box, and a entry box to put the answer to the question. Push the send button. Then after the answer is  sent pop up the next text box as a response to the entry box.  Then give them another entry box to type an answer, send the answer with a button, and them again a text box as the response.  Do I need to use something other than a text box, entry box, and button.  I'm so new to using tkinter it is confusing me as to how to get it to do as I want it. Here is my code so far.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, bg='lightgray')
frame.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
root.title("Uganda Project")

#This is the first Question
T1= Text(frame, height=3, width=37)
T1.pack()
T1.insert(END, "Did you take your medicine?\n 1= Yes\n 2= No\n")
T1.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')

#Make an entry box to answer the question in
e1 = Entry(master=frame, fg='black', bg='lightgray', width=37)
e1.pack()

def answer1():
    """ What to do with the answer in the entry box"""
    answer1 = e1.get()
    return answer1

#Make a Send button to send the answer from the entry box to the definition 
of answer1 
send = Button(frame, text="Send", command=answer1)
send.pack()

#This is the second question
if answer1==1:       
    T2 = Text(frame, height=1, width=37)
    T2.pack()
    T2.insert(END, "Good Job! Text 0 to end conversation")
    T2.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')

elif answer1==2:
    T2 = Text(frame, height=3, width=37)
    T2.pack()
    T2.insert(END, "1= Did you forget?\n2= Did you run out of medicine?\n3= 
    Did it have bad side effects?\n")
    T2.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')

else:
    T2 = Text(frame, height=3, width=37)
    T2.pack()
    T2.insert(END, "I did not understand your response.")
    T2.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')

#Make an entry box to answer the question in
e2 = Entry(master=frame, fg='black', bg='lightgray', width=37)
e2.pack()

def answer2():
    """ What to do with the answer in the entry box"""
    answer2 = e2.get()
    return answer2

#Make a Send button to send the answer from the entry box to the definition 
of answer2 
send = Button(frame, text="Send", command=answer2)
send.pack()

#This is the response to the second entry box
if answer2==0:
    T3 = Text(frame, height=1, width=37)
    T3.pack()
    T3.insert(END, "Have a good day.")
    T3.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')

elif answer2==1:
    T3 = Text(frame, height=2, width=37)
    T3.pack()
    T3.insert(END, "Take it as your earliest convience.\nDo Not Take two 
    doses at once!\n")
    T3.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')

elif answer2==2:
    T3 = Text(frame, height=2, width=37)
    T3.pack()
    T3.insert(END, "Please contact your doctor or\npharmacy for refills.\n")
    T3.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')

elif answer2==3:
    T3 = Text(frame, height=3, width=37)
    T3.pack()
    T3.insert(END, "Please contact your doctor about\nchanging your 
    medications or\ndealing with your symptoms.\n")
    T3.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')
else:
    T3 = Text(frame, height=3, width=37)
    T3.pack()
    T3.insert(END, "I did not understand your response.")
    T3.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please try to narrow down your question(I think it is _too broad_ right now) and provide a [mcve] _specific_ to it. You can use **`{}`**, or `Ctrl-K` while a code piece is selected to format it better. Also, notice that an indentation is 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

one more code, with previous interface:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Uganda Project")
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='lightgray')
frame.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')

def answer1():
    """ What to do with the answer in the entry box"""
    # This is the second question
    if e1.get () == str (1):
        T2.replace (1.0, tk.END, "Good Job! Text 0 to end conversation")
    elif e1.get () == str (2):
        T2.replace (1.0, tk.END, "1= Did you forget?\n"
                                 "2= Did you run out of medicine?\n"
                                 "3= Did it have bad side effects?\n")

def answer2():
    """ What to do with the answer in the entry box"""
    #This is the response to the second entry box
    if e2.get()==str(0):
        T3.replace (1.0, tk.END, "Have a good day.")
    elif e2.get()==str(1):
        T3.replace (1.0, tk.END, "Take it as your earliest convience.\n"
                                 "Do Not Take two doses at once!\n")
    elif e2.get()==str(2):
        T3.replace (1.0, tk.END, "Please contact your doctor or\n"
                                 "pharmacy for refills.\n")
    elif e2.get()==str(3):
        T3.replace (1.0, tk.END, "Please contact your doctor about\n"
                                 "changing your medications or\n"
                                 "dealing with your symptoms.\n")

#This is the first Question
T1= tk.Text(frame, height=3, width=37)
T1.pack()
T1.insert(tk.END, "Did you take your medicine?\n 1= Yes\n 2= No\n")
T1.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')

#Make an entry box to answer the question in
e1 = tk.Entry(master=frame, fg='black', bg='lightgray', width=37)
e1.pack()

#Make a Send button to send the answer from the entry box to the definition of answer1
send = tk.Button(frame, text="Send", command=answer1)
send.pack()

T2 = tk.Text(frame, height=3, width=37)
T2.pack()
T2.insert(tk.END, "I did not understand your response.")
T2.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')

#Make an entry box to answer the question in
e2 = tk.Entry(master=frame, fg='black', bg='lightgray', width=37)
e2.pack()

T3 = tk.Text(frame, height=3, width=37)
T3.pack()
T3.insert(tk.END, "I did not understand your response.")
T3.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')

#Make a Send button to send the answer from the entry box to the definition of answer2
send2 = tk.Button(frame, text="Send", command=answer2)
send2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code (I have changed a few things as well as adding others to hopefully do the job). Its not the most efficient or the best structured code but it does the job (for me at least):

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime

root = Tk ()
root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: answer1 ())
f = Frame(root, bg='lightgray')
f.grid (sticky = "nsew")
Grid.columnconfigure (root, 0, weight = 1)
Grid.rowconfigure (root, 0, weight = 1)
root.title("Uganda Project")

#This is the first Question
Bar = Scrollbar (f)
T = Listbox (f, fg='white', bg='blue', yscrollcommand = Bar.set, width = 50, height = 20)
Bar.config (command = T.yview)
T.grid (row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")
Bar.grid (row = 0, column = 2, sticky = "ns")
Grid.columnconfigure (f, 0, weight = 1)
Grid.rowconfigure (f, 0, weight = 1)
T.insert (END, "Support:")
T.insert (END, "    Did you take your medicine?")
T.insert (END, "    1= Yes")
T.insert (END, "    2= No")

#Make an entry box to answer the question in
e = Entry(f, fg='black', bg='lightgray')
e.focus_force ()
e.grid (row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "ew")

def answer1():
    """ What to do with the answer in the entry box"""
    answer1 = e.get()
    T.insert (END, "You: " + answer1)
    e.delete (0, END)
    if answer1=="1":       
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    Good Job! Text 0 to end conversation")
        send.config (command = answer2)
        root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: answer2 ())

    elif answer1=="2":
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    1= Did you forget?")
        T.insert (END, "    2= Did you run out of medicine?")
        T.insert (END, "    3= Did it have bad side effects?")
        send.config (command = answer2)
        root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: answer2 ())

    else:
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    I did not understand your response.")

    return answer1

#Make a Send button to send the answer from the entry box to the definition of answer1 
send = Button(f, text="Send", command=answer1)
send.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

#This is the second question

#Make an entry box to answer the question in

def save ():
    with open ("Log - %s.txt" % str (datetime.datetime.now ()).replace (":", "."), "w") as f: f.write ("\n".join (T.get (0, END)))

def answer2():
    """ What to do with the answer in the entry box"""
    answer2 = e.get()
    T.insert (END, "You: " + answer2)
    e.delete (0, END)
    #This is the response to the second entry box
    if answer2=="0":
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    Have a good day.")
        send.config (text = "OK", command = root.destroy)
        root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: root.destroy ())
        save ()
        e.pack_forget ()

    elif answer2=="1":
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    Take it as your earliest convience.")
        T.insert (END, "    Do Not Take two doses at once!")
        root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: root.destroy ())
        send.config (text = "OK", command = root.destroy)
        save ()
        e.pack_forget ()

    elif answer2=="2":
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    Please contact your doctor or")
        T.insert (END, "    pharmacy for refills.\n")
        root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: root.destroy ())
        send.config (text = "OK", command = root.destroy)
        save ()
        e.pack_forget ()

    elif answer2=="3":
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    Please contact your doctor about")
        T.insert (END, "    changing your medications or")
        T.insert (END, "    dealing with your symptoms.")
        root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: root.destroy ())
        send.config (text = "OK", command = root.destroy)
        save ()
        e.pack_forget ()

    else:
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    I did not understand your response.")

    return answer2

root.mainloop ()


#Make a Send button to send the answer from the entry box to the definition of answer1 
send = Button(f, text="Send", command=answer1)
send.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

#This is the second question

#Make an entry box to answer the question in

def answer2():
    """ What to do with the answer in the entry box"""
    answer2 = e.get()
    T.insert (END, "You: " + answer2)
    e.delete (0, END)
    #This is the response to the second entry box
    if answer2=="0":
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    Have a good day.")
        send.config (text = "OK", command = root.destroy)
        root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: root.destroy ())
        e.pack_forget ()

    elif answer2=="1":
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    Take it as your earliest convience.")
        T.insert (END, "    Do Not Take two doses at once!")
        root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: root.destroy ())
        send.config (text = "OK", command = root.destroy)
        e.pack_forget ()

    elif answer2=="2":
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    Please contact your doctor or")
        T.insert (END, "    pharmacy for refills.\n")
        root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: root.destroy ())
        send.config (text = "OK", command = root.destroy)
        e.pack_forget ()

    elif answer2=="3":
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    Please contact your doctor about")
        T.insert (END, "    changing your medications or")
        T.insert (END, "    dealing with your symptoms.")
        root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: root.destroy ())
        send.config (text = "OK", command = root.destroy)
        e.pack_forget ()

    else:
        T.insert (END, "Support:")
        T.insert (END, "    I did not understand your response.")

    return answer2

root.mainloop()
```

Below is an example of how different projects can be called assuming:

1) The project is in the same directory as the calling code

2) The project is named after its function (so `Uganda Project` respectively)

I have also created a `Rwanda Project` as well to show how you can add extra pojects other than just the `Uganda Project`.

```
from tkinter import *
import importlib, threading, time, logging

PROJECTS = ("Uganda Project", "Rwanda Project")

def constructWindow ():
    global root, close
    close, wait = False, False
    logging.basicConfig (format = "%(message)s")
    while True:
        root = Tk ()
        root.title ("Main Menu")
        Label (root, text = "Which project would you like to run?").grid ()
        for project in PROJECTS: Button (root, text = project, command = lambda project = project: callProject (project)).grid ()
        root.protocol ("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closeWindow)
        root.mainloop ()
        while wait: time.sleep (0.1)
        if close: break
def callProject (project):
    global wait
    wait = True
    root.destroy ()
    try: importlib.import_module (project)
    except ImportError: logging.warn ("Cannot find project.")
    wait = False
def closeWindow ():
    global close
    close = True
    root.destroy ()
if __name__ == "__main__": constructWindow ()
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep the original messages and answers?  I'm trying to demo a conversation via text messaging without actually sending and receiving text messages.

Comment: Please see my updated version. It isn't quite as 'nice looking' but it still does the job.

Comment: Is there any way I can save the conversation in a file for later and what kind of file should I use?  Thank you for your help! It works great!!!

Comment: Please see my edited version (it creates a log file for each conversation). I am also very glad to be of help.

Comment: I have five programs that are the same as this program that I have to make into one program that you can choose to run each of the other programs from it. I'm trying to figure out how to make the selection of the program to run and for them all not to run at once. The call log works.

Comment: I also need to figure out a way to start the process over again if I receive a message that is not one of the predetermined answers and let them try again. The else part of the answer where is says I did not understand your response.  I'm so new to doing this stuff.  I feel like every time I have to change something it's like a huge deal because I have no idea what I'm doing. I am definitely learning from you.

Comment: I hope my new code does the job (it can keep things simpler as you can keep each project in its own file)

Comment: So I got all my programs to run from one program.  Thanks for your input.  I've gotten answer1 to restart if they answer anything other than 1 or 2, but I can't get answer2 to work correctly to restart because if they answered 1 to answer 1, but messed up on answer2 by putting anything other than a 0 and they answered 1,2, or 3 they get the message box for if they answer a 2 to answer1.  I'm trying to get it to basically restart the process if they mess up.

Comment: else:
            T.insert (END, "Support:")
            T.insert (END, "    I did not understand your response.")
            T.insert (END, "    Please try again.")
            T.insert (END, "Support:")
            T.insert (END, "    Did you take your medicine?")
            T.insert (END, "    1= Yes")
            T.insert (END, "    2= No")
            answer1 = e.get()
            T.insert (END, "Patient: " + answer1)
            e.delete (0, END)

Comment: if answer1=="1":       
                T.insert (END, "Support:")
                T.insert (END, "    Good Job! Text 0 to end conversation")
                send.config (command = answer2)
                root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: answer2 ())

            elif answer1=="2":
                T.insert (END, "Support:")
                T.insert (END, "    1= Did you forget?")
                T.insert (END, "    2= Did you run out of medicine?")
                T.insert (END, "    3= Did it have bad side effects?")

Comment: send.config (command = answer2)
                root.bind ("<Return>", lambda event: answer2 ())
        return answer1

Comment: That's for answer1.  That's how I got it to restart question 1.